# Textmate error dialogue stuck open

Tags: textmate

I accidentally copy-pasted the contents of a file into the name of a file. Textmate has opened an error dialogue box with the contents of my file, beginning with "The item couldn’t be saved because the file name..."

This error box reaches far below the bottom my screen, and won't let me close it as the close mechanism is at the bottom of the dialogue box. I cannot resize the box, I cannot close the box. I also cannot access any of my open (and unsaved) textmate files. I could force-quit, but I would lose my unsaved changes.

How can I close this error box?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally dialog boxes can be dismissed by pressing escape or <kbd>⌘.</kbd>.

But if you are using TextMate 2 then there should be little concern about force quitting, as it will restore your session on relaunch (including unsaved changes).

Comment: Good to know about the force quitting. I can't seem to replicate the issue, but I was pretty sure I tried ESC multiple times. Thank you.